# JCR session closed by container causes duplicate attempt to close session

Tags: java-ee-6, jackrabbit, jcr, jca, content-repository

In my EJB I use a JCR session to store a File. I then logout of the session and throw a CDI event. The EJB which observes the CDI event then creates a new JCR session in which it wants to use the stored file. (Note: I had to add a delay in order to get this to work because for some reason the file wasn't available directly after storing it). After the method is done with using the file I also logout of this session. However after 15 minutes I get the exception  "Attempt to close session-a84d60ac-1c8f-4cad-bc5a-84102b12f8e5-385 after it has already been closed." with stacktrace :

```
Stack trace of the duplicate attempt to close session-c7bc3b30-9a5f-4922-bf80-8f197c583370-389 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.close(SessionState.java:280) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.logout(SessionImpl.java:943) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl.logout(XASessionImpl.java:392) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnection.cleanup(JCAManagedConnection.java:169) [jackrabbit-jca-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at ...
```

and after 1 hour :

```
Unclosed session detected. The session was opened here: java.lang.Exception: Stack Trace 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:222) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:239) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl.<init>(XASessionImpl.java:99) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:na] 
 at ...
```

I believe this is because the application server (Glassfish v.3.1.2.2) tries to close the session I already closed. But when I don't close any sessions, I also get an exception where it says that the pool size limit is reached. How can I avoid my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use the session across threads? Are you passing the session to other methods which are also trying to close it? It might be worth double checking your code just to make sure thats not happening. Also, "I had to add a delay", thats a really bad code smell. Fix the problem, not the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Jackrabbit in a XA transaction.

I had a similar problem with JBoss, which I resolved by using a non XA datasource different from the one for my EJBs.
Look into for more info :
http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/How-to-handle-XA-Transactions-td521875.html

Comment: So using local transactions should work then ? Or do I have to change something in the config of my repository.xml ? I think I remember trying this with local transactions and getting the same error but I'm not sure. I'll try it later that day and let you know

Comment: with local transaction I get the error : System Exception com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Local transaction is not supported at com.sun.enterprise.resource.ConnectorXAResource.getResourceHandle(ConnectorXAResource.java:255) at com.sun.enterprise.resource.ConnectorXAResource.resetAssociation(ConnectorXAResource.java:266) at ...  What do I have to do ?

Comment: How did you deployed your repository in Glassfish ? It looks like it is deployed as a resource in the server. Did you look at this page on their wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JackrabbitOnJBoss?highlight=%28transaction%29) it has an example on how to use it from a session bean.

Comment: yes I'm using the resource adapter version. I had a look at the wiki but I already know how to use the repository within a session bean

Comment: Do you use an XA datasource through JNDI for Jackrabbit ? I had too many problems on Jboss with it but I was in an EJB 2.1 :(